# How to get/access Certificate status/information for the browser (IE etc.)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, certificate, activex

I want to install a trusted Root Certificate. Now, I made a batch/exe file which simply install the certificate by clicking it. Now, I want to attach the file with a web page which will automatically download/run the `exe/batch` and install it. Now, this part is also done by following code (it works as activex object):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->


<SCRIPT Language="JScript">



function fnShellExecuteJ()

{

var objShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

objShell.ShellExecute("D:\\New folder\\New folder\\RootInstaller.exe", "", "", "open", 1);

}

<HTML>

</SCRIPT> 

<BODY>


<body onLoad="javascript:fnShellExecuteJ();"> 

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Now, I want to check the certificate is installed or not ? if the root certificate is installed in the "IE>Tools>Internet Option>Content>Certificate>Trusted Root Certificate authorities", then it will not try to open the installer and skip. But, if it is not installed, then it will try to install.

In a word, I want to get the installed certificate status to check and then based on that proceed to next.

Thank You for reading this (my English is horrible). And any suggestion/tips/writing will help this newcomer.Thank You.....

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you want to implement it.

The "canonical" way to figure out whether a certificate exists in a specific cert store is with the API: **CertFindCertificateInStore** after you opened the specific store with CertOpenStore (there are several cert stores on your Windows).

Now, the problem is that this is C/C++ code, which you'll have to embed within an ActiveX (or similar). For Windows 7 and 8 I don't think you can avoid that.

For versions prior to Windows 7 (Windows XP, Windows Vista) Microsoft had an a component called CAPICOM, which gave script access to cryptography. If your clients are XP/Vista only you can use that, and then call CAPICOM from the JavaScript on your page (Your users will have to install it).

However, if you are running an executable on your user's computer (to install the certificate), why wouldn't you simply install a trusted ActiveX object (or a BHO) - which you can test for existence in your JavaScript page.

That is:

```
var MyObj;
try {
    MyObj = new ActiveXObject( "MyActiveX" );
    alert( 'my object exist' );
} catch( err ) {
    alert( 'my object do not exist' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I do not think either CertFindCertificateInStore or CAPICOM will be help in my case. And I want to install certificate from a batch/EXE which has been created by me. So, trusted activex object process can not be done.
All I want a way to get that, my certificate "Root X" is installed in the browser or not ? if installed then skip but if not installed then install.......
But thank you very much for your reply. I am a novice developer so I do not know I could explain all the aspects or not (forgive me for that)......